# Users connected to postgres schema

Tags: postgresql

With the sql 
select * from pg_stat_activity 
I can see all users connected to my database, I need something like that to show which schema is using each user connected

Comment: There is no "connected to schema", you cannot _connect_ to a _schema_. A connection can make use of objects inside the schema, have open transaction or locks on them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to a schema, so it isn't clear what you are looking for.  A schema is just a logical namespace for groups within the system.   Now:

1. Determining which schemas a user has access to requires connecting to the relevant db and checking.  You can't do this globally since schemas are not global objects.
2. It should be possible to show the search_path since this only attaches to global objects (databases and roles), but I could not figure out how to do this by glancing through the system catalog docs.  That's probably where you'd have to start if that's what you wanted to look for.